# How to get class/function/line name in a function outside a class

Tags: php, debugging

#### Example:

```
class myExample
{
    public function example_fn()
    {
        $example_val = $this->some_fn();
        _debug( $example_val, _get_position() );
    }
}

/**
 * Debug function
 */
function _debug( $input, $position )
{
    $output  = '<strong>Inside: '.$position.'</strong><br />';
    $output .= '<pre>';
    $output .= print_r( var_export( $input, true ), true );
    $output .= '</pre>';

    return print $output;
}

/**
 * Position function
 */
function _get_position()
{
    return 'Class: '.__CLASS__.' // Function: '.__FUNCTION__.' // Line: '.__LINE__;
}
```

#### Question:

With the current setup, the output returns the values of the position where the `_get_position()` function was *defined*. 
Can I somehow get the Class/function/line from where the `_get_position()` function was called?

Thank you!

Comment: why not just use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)?

Comment: use a debugger? debug_backtrace() is a bit hacky ;)

Comment: @phant0m Normally I use [krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/), but I needed something lightweight, because it will stay in the package.

Comment: Yes. It's a set of classes and the init file contains the debug constant and the debug functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for that:

```
function _get_position()
{
    $stack = debug_backtrace();
    return 'Class: '.$stack[1]['class'].' // Function: '.$stack[1]['function'].' // Line: '.$stack[0]['line'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. That doesn't (completely) work. The index should be `1` for Class and function. :)

Comment: (I hope you can edit your A, as I have on this site too less rep points).

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php